# Angular 2 styles.css compilation error

Tags: angular, web-applications

I am trying to compile my angular 2 application which was compiling successfully before but now isn't. I don't know what the issue is.

This is the error I get. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import path in your styles.css for the material themes has changed. It now is: `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

For more information see:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

And the changelog (2.0.0-beta.3 cesium-cephalopod):
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md